# Does DynamoDB scale when partition key bucket gets huge?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, hash, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Does DynamoDB scale when partition key bucket gets huge? What are the possible solutions if this is really a problem?

Comment: Dynamodb is a managed service, the service ensures it scales and meets the defined sla's. Is there a reason why this would concern you as user of the service.

Comment: @Shibashis Because a single partition bucket has a 10GB limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Yes, DynamoDB scales very well as long as you use the service as intended!

As a user of Dynamo your responsibility is to choose a partition key (and range key combination if need be) that provides a relatively uniform distribution of the data and to allocate enough read and write capacity for your use case. If you do use a range key, this means you should aim to have approximately the same number of elements for each of the partition key values in your table.

As long as you follow this rule, Dynamo will scale very well. Even when you hit the size limit for a partition, Dynamo will automatically split the data in the original partition into two equal sized partitions which will each receive about half the data (again - as long as you did a good job of choosing the partition key and range key). This is very well explained in the [Dynamo DB documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions)

Of course, as your table grows and you get more and more partitions, you will have to allocate more and more read and write capacity to ensure enough is provisioned to sustain all partitions of your table. The capacity is equally distributed to all partitions in your table (except for splits - though, again, if the distribution is uniform even splits will receive capacity uniformly).

For reference, see also: [how partitions work](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html).